# Custom Add to Cart on Bundle product page: Magento2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, bundled-product

I want to customize my bundle product page on magento2 store and want different "add to cart" buttons for all the simple products of that bundle product i.e. if there are 3 products available in a bundle product then there should be 3 "add to cart" buttons each with there respective qty field. 
Currently I have overided my bundle page "catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml" with following code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customize.button" as="customize_button" 
               template="PHPCuong_Cart::catalog/product/view/customize.phtml" after="product.info.price" />
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

And in the customize.phtml I have used following code

```
    <?php 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$__product = $block->getProduct();


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
    $selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getSelectionsCollection(
            $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product),
            $_product
        );
    foreach ($selectionCollection as $product) {
      $addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product); ?>

      <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>

      <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 

        <?php 
            echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey');
            echo $product->getData('name');

        ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $product->getData('entity_id'); ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="">
          <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="">
         <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" id="product-addtocart-button" class="action tocart primary">

           <span>Add to Cart</span>
         </button>
          <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
     </form>
<?php
    } ?>

<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now whenever I am adding any product in the cart then its adding but no data is showing in the mini cart. After checking the local storage in the browser I found that cart data is not creating properly.

Any help will be Appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Although if we go to the shopping cart page then the products show properly.

Comment: Hi @Prashant

Did you get any solution for this, or any reference link. Please share.

I want the same Add to cart for each product, instead of select option for bundle product.